# A glitch that appears on android, but not in unity editor

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a problem making a game. When the game is running in the editor or via unity remote 5. Everything is fine, no problems occur. But when I extract the application and run it on android, there is a glitch that occurs, which never appears when run in editor or unity remote 5.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX4Iq.jpg I've included a screenshot so you guys can know exactly what I'm going through. If something is still unclear, you can try asking in the comments

https://youtu.be/Mo9a-1Z9WgA Display on Android

https://youtu.be/T7W8wBh5i-s Display on unity editor

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think I know the problem, this bug occurs when the game is played on Android 8 and below. So the best way I can do right now is to increase the minimum API to 9 and above